# Export dynamic metadata using x265

Tags: ffmpeg, x264, libx264, libx265

I am working on ffmpeg and x265 for video encoding. From the release note of x265:

> HDR10+ supported. Dynamic metadata may be either supplied as a bitstream via the userSEI field of x265_picture, or as a json jile that can be parsed by x265 and inserted into the bitstream; use --dhdr10-info to specify json file name, and --dhdr10-opt to enable optimization of inserting tone-map information only at IDR frames, or when the tone map information changes.

But I dont know how to export the dynamic metadata from a video sequence as a userSEI or json file. Hope to get solution from you.